# JSON string is not being parsed

Tags: java, android, json

I want to parse a JSON string:

**MyJsonString:**

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 2,
  "count_total": 9,
  "pages": 5,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 432,
      "type": "post",
      "title": "Title 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 434,
      "type": "post",
      "title": "Title 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have gone through:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

The examples work fine,but for that,i edited the JSON string to make it a Java String.

Ex: 
JSON String:

```
{"menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
        {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
        {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
        {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
          ]
    }
}}
```

I edited to:

```
String jsonStr = "{menu: {" + 
        "id: file," + 
        "value: File," + 
        "popup: {" + 
          "menuitem: [" + 
            "{value: New, onclick: CreateNewDoc()}," + 
            "{value: Open, onclick: OpenDoc()}," + 
            "{value: Close, onclick: CloseDoc()}" + 
          "]" + 
        "}" + 
      "}}";
```

But when i try to parse this myJsonString after accordingly editing it to be a valid Java String and run the project,it gives me warning and it does not display the Toast message which gives me titles.

Logcat:

```
10-19 18:36:45.972: WARN/System.err(1250): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 101 of { status :  ok ,count : 2,count_total : 9,pages : 5,posts : [{id : 432,type :  post ,title :  Title 1 ,},{id : 434,type :  post ,title :  Title 2 ,},]}
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong? Even I have no idea,how to make Json String to a valid Java String programatically?

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
   String jsonString="{\" status :  ok \",\"count : 2\",\"count_total : 9\",\"pages : 5\",\"posts\" : [{\" id\" : \"432\",\"type\": \" post\", \"title\" : \" Title 1 \"},{ \"id \": \"434\",\type :  post ,\"title\" : \" Title 2\"}]}";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            String status_value = jsonObj.getString("status");          

            Toast.makeText(context,"Status_value= "+status_value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I tried to toast status value this way.But I can't. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand why you edited the JSON string, the edited version doesn't look like valid JSON formatting to me so that's probably why you are getting an error.

Comment: But in example,it was working.I am new to JSON so i started with example and as it worked,i tried to edit my JSON string likewise.If i should not edit the JSON string,how to use it with Java String object?

Comment: why are you editing JSON string? use as it is. using JSON object and JSON array get the value from it.

Comment: As your two answers both indicate, you put backslashes in to make it a valid Java String.

Comment: I managed to make a valid java string of Json String. Please check the edit.Yet,i am not getting any response in Toast. What is my fault?

Comment: @Hiral: Take a look again at your code and the original. In the original JSON there are quotes next to the `:`; in your code, they are still missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the response of the JSON coming is not a valid one.

```
"count": 2, which is not the correct way it should be in double quotes like this

"count": "2", same way for the rest of the response String also.
```

**UPDATED:**

You exact JSONString that you have created is wrong, just replace my string and checkout.

**First String**

```
String jsonString = "{\"status\": \"ok\",\"count\": \"2\",\"count_total\": \"9\",\"pages\": \"5\",\"posts\":" +
        "[{\"id\": \"432\",\"type\": \"post\",\"title\": \"Title 1\"}," +
        "{\"id\": \"434\",\"type\": \"post\",\"title\": \"Title 2\"}]}";
```

**Second String**

```
String jsonStr = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\",\"value\": \"File\",\"popup\": {\"menuitem\": " +
            "[{\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"}," +
            "{\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.if i do that way,how would it be a valid Java String? I mean,making it "count":"2",gives me error at ":".

Comment: Thanks.It really helped me making a valid Json string. But still, I am not getting proper response in Toast.

Comment: You are creating a wrong JSON string check my updated answer. I had created JSON String for you that you want. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The string in your java code is NOT a valid JSON string. you do not enclode the strings with quotes. try this one:

```
 String example = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]";
```

This should give you a string array.